# Accessing teamcity parameters in kotlin DSL

Tags: kotlin, teamcity

I am creating a kotlin DSL for a TeamCity project, and want to get the current branch name in the actual kotlin script.

If I run a script step, the current branch renders correctly

```java
script {
    name="print branch"
    scriptContent = """echo "Branch is  %teamcity.build.branch%""""
}
```

From the actual `settings.kts`, I don't seem to have access to it

```kotlin
val currentBranch = DslContext.getParameter("teamcity.build.branch") //yields '<placeholder-1>'
```

How can I get this parameter in my Kotlin code?

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out it isn't possible - the DSL is merely used to express a config, and isn't invoked during the build process.  In my case, I wanted to enable or disable some steps according to whether I was on `main` or a feature branch, so I created 2 `BuildDefinition` objects,, which subclassed the main build, passing in a bool of whether the branch was `main`.  With that, I was able to enable or disable build steps and update the VCS triggers for each build

Comment: It's amazing such a basic fundamental aspect, it's so hard to find in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

What seems to work for me is

```
object : BuildType({
   val changeList = if ("%teamcity.build.branch%" == "master") "" else "-%teamcity.build.branch%"
   ...
   steps {
       maven {
           jvmArgs = "-Xmx1024m -Xss1g -Drevision=1.1.%build.counter% -Dchangelist=$changeList"
       }
   }
})
```

YMMV

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a VCS root for each branch, DslContext.settingsRoot is the VCS root the Kotlin is executing against.

From our Kotlin which is used to build against several different branches:

```
val branchName = "${DslContext.settingsRoot}" // DslContext.settingsRoot.name - .name seems to be blank
```